# Find node using another node and relationship

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

How to check whether a node exists using relationship and other node of the relationship?

```
 A ->(IN) B
```

I want to check if B is present with node A having relationship IN using py2neo

I tried this cypher query:

```
MATCH (a { name:'xyz' })<-[:IN]-(b)
Return b
```

But I was looking for something in py2neo like find function?

Comment: Are you using cypher? what are your labels? what's the context? what have you tried (as Stefan already said). You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using cypher, so you should try this:

```
OPTIONAL Match (A:Foo)-[:IN]->(B:Bar)
return RETURN B IS NOT NULL AS exists
```

Using case allows you to return a boolean based on the existence of B using an optional match.

Comment: Your `RETURN` clause can be simplified to: `RETURN B IS NOT NULL AS exists`.

Comment: I was not sure if it was correct, so I did a CASE, thank you, will edit asap :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `py2neo` function `match-one()` (documented on [this page](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html)). It will return one such relationship, should any exist.

If you want to see all such relationships, you can use the `match()` function instead.